# Mypy does not detect errors regarding the use of NamedTuple inside functions

Tags: python, mypy, namedtuple

In the following code the defintions of `x2` and `x3` are obviously wrong, yet mypy does not complain.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class X(NamedTuple):
    a: float
    b: float
    c: float

def foo():
    x1 = X(1, 2, 3)
    x2 = X(1, 2)
    x3 = X("1", 2, 3)
```

If I remove the function declaration and put the three lines into the main file scope, then mypy correctly identifies both errors

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class X(NamedTuple):
    a: float
    b: float
    c: float

x1 = X(1, 2, 3)
x2 = X(1, 2)
x3 = X("1", 2, 3)
```

Why is that, what can I do about it?

Im running
python                    3.9.5
mypy                      0.931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foo` function is untyped, you must say to `mypy` to type it with `->`:

```
def foo() -> None:
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise, that mypy does not look into untyped functions at all. Indeed adding at least the -> None, solves the issue.